# How to remove square brackets from the single value list output in python?

Tags: python, list

Output of the code is okay but with single value list, it shows output with sqaure brackets like ['c'].How can i remove these square brackets to get the output c only?

```
    favorite_languages = {
    'jen' : ['python','ruby'],
    'sarah' : ['c'],
    'edward' : ['ruby','go'],
    'phil' : ['python','haskell'],
     }
    for name,languages in favorite_languages.items():
        if len(languages) > 1:
            print("\n" + name.title() + "'s favorite languages are:")
            for language in languages:
                print("\t" + language.title() )
        else:
            print("\n" + name.title() + "'s favorite language is:" + str(favorite_languages[name]))
```

Comment: Just use `favorite_languages[name][0]` in your `else` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `languages[0]` which will only print the first element of the list:

```
else:
    print("\n" + name.title() + "'s favorite language is:" + languages[0])
```

Note that `language` just like `languages[0]` is already a `str`.